# Interpretation of: *(Statement 1 holds), if (Statement 2)*

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

I have come across a question in a Real Analysis assignment (contents of the question are not important), where I need to prove that:

*(Statement 1 holds), if (Statement 2)*.

I'm confused about the terminology here. Do we need to show that

- if Statement 2 is true, then Statement 1 holds, OR
- Statement 1 is true only if Statement 2 holds?

Had the question been, *if (Statement 2), (Statement holds)*, the former would work. However, the given terminology in the question has confused me.

Comment: `B if A` (that is, `if A, then B`)doesn't require a comma, so maybe the comma is causing confusion. $\quad$ P.S. In your question, are `(Statement 1)` and `(Statement 1 holds)` and `(Statement 1 is true)` synonyms?

Comment: Actually yes, they are synonyms. Maybe I could have used a single terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show :
Statement 2 $\Rightarrow$ Statement 1.

Had they mentioned "Only if", you would have to show the opposite implication.